# How to call a puppet function from a different module than the module it is defined in

Tags: function, module, puppet, manifest

I have defined a puppet function `check_value` in module `test_one`

```
test_one
 |- functions
     |- check_value.pp
```

and the function declaration:

```
test_one::check_value(String $check) >> String {
    ...
}
```

I declared a class `test_functions` within the same module.

```
test_one
 |- functions
     |- check_value.pp
 |- manifests
     |- test_functions.pp
```

Everything seems to be perfect and I can call this function `check_value` from the class `test_functions` within the same module and could fetch the return value.

However, if I call this function from another module, I get `Evaluation Error: Unknown function: ...`

```
test_two
 |- manifests
     |- test_external_function.pp
```

In the class `test_external_function`, I tried several ways to call `check_value` but with no luck:

```
1. $x = test_one::check_value("t")


2. include test_one
   $x = check_value("t")  


3. include test_one
   $x = test_one::check_value("t")
```

All trials have failed. Is it possible to call and use these puppet (non-ruby) functions from another module? I couldn't seem to find a way. Google is of no help so far!

As per the puppet documentation, it is possible:
[Puppet Functions](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_write_functions_in_puppet.html)

> Functions are autoloaded and made available to other modules unless those modules specify dependencies. Once a function is written and available (in a module where the autoloader can find it), you can call that function in any Puppet manifest that lists the containing module as a dependency, and also from your main manifest.

Comment: Is your other module specifying dependencies in its `metadata.json`?

Comment: @MattSchuchard, +1 yes thank you! I've explicitly not mentioned any dependencies but looks like `puppet generate module` has added stdlib as a dependency. If I remove the stdlib dependency from metadata.json, the module is no more recognized as available.

Comment: So was this the problem: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_write_functions_in_puppet.html#calling-a-function

Comment: @MattSchuchard, yes that's the problem! I added `test_one` into the dependencies list in `metadata.json` of `test_two` and it worked, without a problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to a relatively new requirement introduced in Puppet coding that is documented [here](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_write_functions_in_puppet.html#calling-a-function). Specifically:

> Note that if a module has a list of dependencies in its metadata.json file, it loads custom functions only from those specific dependencies.

Typically, module generation via either the PDK or `puppet module generate` will create a placeholder `metadata.json` with `puppetlabs/stdlib` as a dependency. This is normally fine in practice, but it will break autoloading custom functions from other modules.

In this case (and I guess you would also say in general per best practices), you would want to specify other modules with custom functions you are invoking as dependencies in your `metadata.json` for the module. For example, in `test_two/metadata.json`, you could have something like:

```
"dependencies": [
  { "name": "org_name/test_one", "version_requirement": ">= 1.0.0 < 2.0.0" },
]
```

with full documentation on specifying dependencies [here](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/modules_metadata.html#specifying-dependencies).